# Why does mov rax,cr0 cause a segmentation fault in nasm 64 bit

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, nasm, segmentation-fault

I needed to write a code to test the LSB of `cr0` in nasm. The code is as follows:

```
section .data
temp : db 00h   ;Temporary storage
nl : db 10      ;Memory which holds decimal 10 to print a newline 

section .text
global _start
_start:
mov rax,cr0        ;Move contents of cr0 into rax
bt rax,0           ;Test LSB of rax 
jnc l1             ;If 0, move 30 into temp (ASCII for '0')  
mov byte[temp],31h ;Else, move 31 into temp
jmp l2
l1:
mov byte[temp],30h
l2:
print temp,1       ;Print value of temp
print nl,1

mov rax,60         ;Exit syscall
mov rdi,0
syscall
```

The code, when run, causes a segmentation fault. It occurs because of the instruction `mov rax,cr0`. When that instruction is commented, no segmentation fault occurs. Why is this so? Does this have something to do with user's privilege level? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, exactly. `CR0` is a system register, not accessible in user mode. If you consult the instruction set reference you will see it says: _64-Bit Mode Exceptions #GP(0) If the current privilege level is not 0._

Comment: Any workaround to this issue? Or is my direction of thinking incorrect? @Jester

Comment: What do you even want to do with the content of `cr0`?

Comment: LSB of CR0 is PE, and since you are already running in 64 bit long mode, that bit is going to be 1. No need to check.

Comment: As a college assignment, we need to switch from real mode to protected mode, and print the contents of GDTR, LDTR, IDTR, TR and MSW. All resources on the net were a little too complicated, so I intended to start with just reading contents of cr0 to test which mode I am currently operating in. @fuz

Comment: Launch a linux in a vm, say bochs, then print the registers in the debugger. Or write a kernel module but that's probably more trouble than what it's worth.

Comment: Is there a way to change the user's privilege level? @Jester

Comment: Do you think that may be a security hole? :) No there is none, not even root can do that although he can at least get iopl but that doesn't help you here.

Comment: If your assignment involves real mode, then you have to start from an unprotected operating system (or no operating system at all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `mov rax,cr0`, you can use the [`smsw` instruction](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SMSW.html) to store the low 16 bit of `cr0`. This instruction is not privileged and works on all rings:

```
smsw ax
test ax,1
jnz protected_mode
```

Comment: You missed a tiny little detail though: _can be used in application programs if CR4.UMIP = 0._

Comment: @Jester To be fair, I don't think any processors that actually implement UMIP are out yet.

Comment: That may be, but clearly this loophole is being closed too ;) It might work for now though.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to execute a privileged instruction whilst you are not in a privileged mode.
According to the [instruction set reference:](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV-1.html)

> Protected Mode Exceptions
>   #GP(0)
>   If the current privilege level is not 0.

Because you are running in user mode you cannot run privileged instructions.

In order to enter real mode you must first get a privilege level in ring 0.
In order for this to happen you must be executing in kernel mode.
See [fuz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41922263/650492) on how to do this in Linux.

For more info on entering and exiting real mode see: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/45788/the-real-protected-long-mode-assembly-tutorial-for